# How to add a Authorization header into a HTTP request by using Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, headers, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

Is there a way to add a token into my HTTP request without using Postman or cURL?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The title of the question and tags indicates you want to use Chrome Dev Tools to accomplish this, but the body of your question seems open ended. When you say without Postman or cURL, does that imply exclusion of all third-party tools (and perhaps even extensions)?